# Regular expression for multiple brackets

Tags: regex

I was trying to figure out regular expression to search below contents.

```
authentication { 
admin-enabled enabled 
syslog-admin-state disabled 
server  1.2.3.4 {
          address 1.2.3.4
          priority 1
          port 49
          admin-enabled enabled
        }
        server  2.3.4.5 {
          address 2.3.4.5
          priority 2
          port 2
          admin-enabled enabled
        }

}
```

Comment: What is your question? Which regular expressions have you tried?

Comment: I have tried this one " authentication\s*{(\n|.)*?} "

Comment: What is your programming language (if any) ? And what do you want to extract?

Comment: I'm writing on python looking an regexp to extract nested brackets details from authentication opening bracket to closing bracket

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should match your text; using atomic group syntax to handle the nested brackets.

```
authentication\s*(\{(?>[^{}]+|(?1))*\})
```

Please note that if you are using PHP, you may have a problem with the ?> part, as it could be interpreted as the end of the script. In this case you can use ?: instead.

```
authentication\s*(\{(?:[^{}]+|(?1))*\})
```

If you are using Python, then you can achieve your requirement by using the new regex module.

Here is how to install it

```
sudo yum install python-devel
sudo pip install regex
```

And here is the working sample of Python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import regex
#import re

line = "\
other_object1 { \
  test1 {\
    test1\
  }\
}\
\
authentication { \
admin-enabled enabled \
syslog-admin-state disabled \
server  1.2.3.4 {\
          address 1.2.3.4\
          priority 1\
          port 49\
          admin-enabled enabled\
        }\
        server  2.3.4.5 {\
          address 2.3.4.5\
          priority 2\
          port 2\
          admin-enabled enabled\
        }\
}"

pattern = "authentication\s*(\{(?>[^{}]+|(?1))*\})"
matchObj = regex.search(pattern, line)

if matchObj:
   print "matchObj.group() : ", matchObj.group()
else:
   print "No match!!"
```

Comment: I tried to use same expression on python but it's showing pattern error.

Comment: You'll need to have the regex python module to get it working. I updated the answer to mach your requirement.

Comment: Thanks !! It's working

Comment: Would you please mark it as the answer then?